# What does the address really means in "Exception thrown at <address> in app.exe.." dialog?

Tags: c++, debugging

I am deliberately passing a NULL handle to `GetExitCodeThread()` in this very simple function below to understand something.

```
void CStringDemoDlg::OnBnClickedButtonTest()
{
    DWORD dwExitCode = 0;
    HANDLE hThread = 0;

    GetExitCodeThread(hThread, &dwExitCode);
}
```

In regular run, nothing bad happens but when I run with my memory checker tool, it catches a NULL handle is being passed and stops the execution and I see the handle is NULL, so far so good.

Now if I choose to continue debugging, it throws an exception below.

[image]

But the address it mentions (773bbb47) doesn't match to anything in registers or anything else. The value of registers are:

```
0:000> r
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=0043e104 edx=0043e105 esi=77560560 edi=0043e6c4
eip=77560572 esp=0043e568 ebp=0043e588 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!NtQueryInformationThread+0x12:
77560572 83c404
```

On top of that, it was throwing the dialog above after it threw first chance exception but after subsequent runs it no longer throw the exception error dialog but first chance is thrown (seems like it is being handled now without any code change!?)

My question is what does the address really mean in this error dialog? Why does it not correspond to anything?

If I try to set breakpoint on this address, the result is below (it doesn't find symbol) but the symbols are really not an issue as they are loaded (i am running from source code). This is just another unexpected error.

```
0:000> bm r 773bbb47
No matching code symbols found, no breakpoints set.
```

I know I should not be worrying about this error dialog because it obviously resulted from the NULL handle but I wanted to understand why such a follow through with an exception for memory which doesn't correspond to anything!

Comment: Presumably the address is somewhere in the code of your "memory checker tool". Which is what?

Comment: Good thought, I am using application verifier but that module address range is 10450000 - 104b0000 and that would put this address out of its range though. When I do `lm a 773bbb47` to find which module this address belongs to, it doesn't return any module!

Comment: Break and have a look at the stack frame window

Comment: The exception is likely being raised directly inside your own executable code, that would explain why the address does not correspond to any external modules the app is using (like `kernel32.dll`, where `GetExitCodeThread()` resides). Your verifier tool is likely hooking into your call to `GetExitCodeThread()` and throwing an exception at the call site if bad input is about to be passed to the OS function. The debugger then sees that exception like any other before your app sees it. The popup is coming from the debugger.

Comment: @RemyLebeau If it helps to know, this is a brand new default MFC application where only thing I added was this button handler. I saw this behaviour in my real application but went on to create a simple demo where I was easily able to produce it. 

You seem to imply `lmi` doesn't show the main module? It shows StringDemo address range is 013d0000 - 0141c000 which is my main application and this address is again out of range.